# Sending data over a socket using parallels

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have an application that opens a socket and sends information over it. This functionality is encapsulated in a class.

I thought that it could be easy to work in parallel if I run this feature with `Parallel.ForEach`. In this way, each task would open/close a socket and send over it (to the same ip/port). This solution doesn't works.

Second way, I am implementing the socket operation in asynchronous way, and the behavior is that    the server receives all data from first task and later the rest of data from other task. From the server side, there's no parallel behavior.

I am searching and reading information about this but I can't solve this problem.

Any ideas? Do you have a complete sample of using socket with Parallel library? Or any complete sample of using sockets in multithreading environment?

Complementary information:

I have a LINQ expression that returns a list of files. This list is processed as this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(AllFiles, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxDegreeOfParallelism }, currentFile => 
{
    ProcessFiles(currentFile);
});
```

...

ProcessFiles sumarized:

```
void ProcessFile (string currentFile)
{
    MyTcpClient client = null;

    try
    {  
        var AllLinesInFiles = // LINQ Expression that returns a list of strings    
        int port = 23000;
        client = new MyTcpServer(ip, port);                

        foreach (string data in AllLinesInFiles)
        {
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!client.IsOk)
                {
                    client.Connect(false);
                    if (!client.IsOk)
                        break;
                }
                client.SendMessage(tmpLine2);
        }                   
    }
}            
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    if ((client != null) && (client.IsOk))
        client.Close();                
}
```

}

MyTcpClient, synchronous version is:

```
public class MyTcpClient : IDisposable 
{
    private static object objLock = new object();
    public int Port = ...
    public IPAddress IPAddress = ...              
    private string _Host;
    private TcpClient _client = null;        
    private Stream _stream = null;

    static MyTcpClient()
    {
    }

    public MyTcpClient(string PassedIPAddress, Int32 PassedPort)
    {
        try
        {                
            this.IPAddress = PassedIPAddress;
            this.Port = PassedPort;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public TcpClient TcpClient
    {
        get { return _client; }
        set { _client = value; }
    }

    public X509Certificate Certificate
    {
        get { return _certificate; }
        set { _certificate = value; }
    }

    public bool IsOk
    {
        get 
        {
            return ((_client != null) && (_client.Connected));           
        }
    }

    public void Connect(bool isSecure)
    {
        if (IsOk == false)
        {                
            _client = new TcpClient(this.IPAddress.ToString(), this.Port);                
            _stream = null;

            try
            {                                     
                NetworkStream networkStream = _client.GetStream();
                _stream = (NetworkStream)networkStream;

            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...                    
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        if (_client != null && IsOk)
        {
            byte[] dgram = EncodingHelper.GetEncoding().GetBytes(message);

            lock (MyTcpClient.objLock)                
            {
                _stream.Write(dgram, 0, dgram.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(byte[] dgram)
    {
        if (_client != null && IsOk)
        {
            lock (MyTcpClient.objLock)                
            {
                _stream.Write(dgram, 0, dgram.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_stream != null)
        {
            _stream.Close();
        }
        if (_client != null)
        {
            _client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And for the Asynchronous version I have used the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx
When I use asynchronous socket client, I update ProcessFile method but, the idea is open/close the socket in this method.

Comment: Can you provide any code samples that might show the specific problem you're encountering? It'll be easier to provide assistance if we can see what you've attempted already.

Comment: Thanks M.Babcock. I've tried to complete my question with code.

Comment: I'm not clear on what's not working for you. You cannot send in parallel over a single TCP connection, so you have to open multiple if you want that. Or compute the data in parallel and send it single-threadedly. What's your problem regarding those approaches?

Comment: Hi, I do the work inside ProcessFiles. Here I open/send/close the socket. In Parallel.ForEach part, when _maxDegreeOfParallelism is greatter than 1, ProcessFiles works in parallel over AllFiles list.

Comment: Yeah, and what is not working? I did not understand that part.

Comment: Hi, in async version, the server receives all the data from one task and next the rest. It seems like one task is sending data and the other is enqueued. There's no alternative sending/receiveng from all task.

Comment: ...and in sync version there is an exception when it writes in stream (_stream.Write)

Comment: @user2499597 What does the exception say?

Comment: in sync version there is a lock problem. I have deleted the line lock (MyTcpClient.objLock). The problem is that the task doesn't works in palallel. The server receives all the message from one task, next all the message from next task... I think that in the server, the message should be received mixed. Some from task one, some from task two ans so on. Now the behavior is similar as a queue. And I'm using Paralell.ForEach to work similar as a multithread.